# Can I rely on the fact the type of the parameter with a default value when involving parameter pack is deduced to an empty pack?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, c++17, default-parameters

Consider an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <class... Ts, size_t... Is>
void foo(std::tuple<Ts...> t,
         std::index_sequence<Is...> = {}) {
   if (sizeof...(Ts) != sizeof...(Is)) {
      foo(t, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>{});
      return;
   }
   (std::cout << ... << std::get<Is>(t));
}

int main() {
   foo(std::make_tuple(1, 2, 3));
}
```

I assume the type of the second parameter of a function `foo` will be by default deduced to `std::integral_sequence<std::size_t>` and as such I don't have to create helper function to use `Is...` indices to tuple elements but can call `foo` with the second parameter set to `std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>{}`.

Can I rely on the fact the type of the parameter with a default value when involving parameter pack is deduced to an empty pack or may it cause undefined behaviour?

Above code compiled using `g++-6` and `clang++-3.6` using `-std=c++1z` option is working as expected.

Comment: Besides the irritating phrasing of the question: Yes (and no undefined behavior)

Comment: @DieterLücking actually I didn't know how to phrase it well... Thank you though

Comment: @DieterLücking: "irritating" is a bit harsh. The title may be inelegant, but it's not offensive or provocative.

Comment: I read the title as "I know this is valid, but is this implemented correctly in current compilers?", but I read the body as "Is this valid?"

Comment: @KerrekSB Besides in your comment, there is no `offensive or provocative` anywhere.

Comment: @hvd my original title was phrased as follows "Will default templated function parameter types involving parameter packs always be deduced as if they had parameter pack empty?" this might be interpreted as you suggest but it wasn't my intention, that is why I've changed the title to the question from the body.

Comment: @W.F. I wouldn't have interpreted the original title that way, just the current title. In the body, it's clear enough from context. Regardless, you've cleared it up now in the comments, that works too. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You're relying on, from [temp.arg.explicit]:

> A trailing template parameter pack (14.5.3) not otherwise deduced will be deduced to an empty sequence of template arguments.

What constitutes a "trailing template parameter pack" is actually never quite defined properly, but all the compilers interpret `Is...` as such here.

---

That said, I wouldn't rely on this, not because it's incorrect but instead because it makes the code difficult to understand. Especially since in this case there's an easy way to pull out all the elements of a lambda: `std::apply()`:

```
template <class... Ts>
void foo(std::tuple<Ts...> t) {
    std::apply([](auto&... args) {
        (std::cout << ... << args);
    }, t);
}
```